# Nodejs: wget, unzip and convert to js without writing to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Well the title says it all, I'm trying to write a script (that runs in a nodejs/express server-side application) that leverages libraries `request`, `unzip` and `xml2js` to perform a task consisting of fetching a zip file from a given url, whose content is an xml file which I need to parse to a javascript object for some further processing.

So far I've managed to come up with:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
/* some init code omitted */
var request = require("request");
var unzip = require("unzip");
var xml2js = require("xml2js");
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

app.get("/import", function(req, res) {
    request("http://path.to/file.zip")
        .pipe(unzip.Parse())
        .on("entry", function(entry) {
            //This is what I'm trying to avoid, which doesn't even work
            entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(entry.path));
            fs.readFile(entry.path, function(err, data) {
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                parser.parseString(data, function(err, obj) {
                    console.log(util.inspect(obj));
                    /* further processing of obj */
                });
            });
        });
});
```

Albeit the fact the contents of the xml file are correctly written to disk, I'm looking for an alternative to this approach for two reasons:

1. to save disk space, since I don't really need to keep the xml file anyway once it has been converted to js
2. it doesn't even work: `fs.readFile` probably starts reading the file before `fs.createWriteStream` is done writing it, because the line `console.log(utils.inspect(obj))` logs `null` (whereas if I run only the innermost `fs.readFile` block and replace `entry.path` with the name of the previously written file, it produces the desired output)

I wish I could jot down a jsFiddle for this but I'm clueless as to how, when it comes to expressjs applications. Cheers.

Comment: Regarding **2**: `fs.createWriteStream(entry.path)` returns a Writable stream, which has a ['finish' event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish). You could start the fs.readFile when the writeStream has finished writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

Piping is unnecessary, parse data directly from the entry stream:

```
app.get("/import", function(req, res) {
request("http://link-top.zip")
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on("entry", function(entry) {
        var chunks = [];
        var res;
        if(entry.path == 'needed.xml') {
            entry.on('data', function(data) {
                chunks.push(data.toString());
            });
            entry.on('end', function () {
                res = chunks.join("");
                parser.parseString(res, function(err, obj) {
                    console.log(util.inspect(obj));
                    /* further processing of obj */
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's a valid answer but unfortunately the `entry.on("data", fn)` event handler gets called multiple times, each with a data chunk that cannot be parsed as a js object. I need the whole content; I could concatenate the various chunks into a string to pass to `parser.parseString` but I'd still need an event of some sort to determine when there are no more chunks to concatenate. The `unzip` library is scarcely documented so I couldn't find the name of the event which signals the completion of the entry, I tried with "end", "finish", "complete" but so far none of these worked...

Comment: One moment, I'll take a look.

Comment: I will, and I'll get back to you tomorrow at around this time. Thanks for now. Andrea

Comment: Ok, I will be waiting for your answer.

Comment: Neat, it works, there were only a couple of mistakes in your code, which I've taken the liberty of fixing (namely pushing the `toString()`ed representation of `data` into the `chunks` array and `join`ing the chunks array with `""` separator, otherwise it uses the comma character which breaks parsing). Cheers.

Comment: Sure, sorry for mistakes. Glad to help you.